# Is this a "pure" AC signal, or biphasic on a DC base?

Tags: ac, dc

These are 'scope images coming from my cochlear implant (Spectra 22, if it matters), to the external coil. The signal type is amplitude shift keying (ASK). The first image is DC-coupled, and the mid-point is about 4.5 V.  The second is AC-coupled, and the mid-point is at 0 V. The documentation I'm reading about cochlear implants talks about a "biphasic signal," which strikes me as simply AC. But measuring this signal from the actual device, it appears that it's up-and-down, but with a DC component so that the signal never goes below 0 V. Am I correct in this interpretation?

[image: DC coupled signal] [image: AC coupled signal]

Answer (score 3):

"Biphasic" means two-state.  Since it's Amplitude Shift Keying, the two states are represented by different amplitudes.  If it was "simply AC" it wouldn't carry any information.

It's difficult to see in your pictures, but the amplitude levels may be hidden in the AC signal, or one of the levels may be "zero" in the alternating component.

Yes, there is a DC offset in the signal you describe. That's another reason for not saying that it is "simply AC".

Answer (score 1):

Biphase is a baseband modulation using 2 phases. 01 or 10

When converted to logic levels, it can be converted to binary data by knowing the protocol if it is Mark, Level or Invert for the binary part. A preamble of some "pattern" is used for bit and byte sync then the data frame will have some format.

The advantage of BiPhase protocol is lack of DC influence and thus may be unipolar or bipolat but us also self-clocking data.  It may appear as 1f, 1.5f and 2f or 1T,1.5T,2T but that depends whether the binary boundary is at the clock leading edge or mid cycle.

One of these protocols was called "*[Manchester](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Manchester_code)* Code" or "biphase-level.